# Is there any open source web server on iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, webserver

I want to make an app. It can launch a web server on iphone to transfer files through wifi.

Is there any open source web server framework available? BTW, I don't want jailbreak my iphone.

Answer (score 1):

You can try mongoose, we used it last time.